# zsh can not save history into .zhistory

Tags: zsh

zsh can not save history. history is blank when open a new terminal.

```
Manjaro% export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Manjaro% sed -e '/^#/d' .zshrc
export HISTSIZE=10000
export SAVEHIST=10000
export HISTFILE="~/.zhistory"
Manjaro% fc -AI
zsh: locking failed for ~/.zhistory: no such file or directory
Manjaro% ls -alF .zhistory
-rw-r--r-- 1 zhuxiaoxi zhuxiaoxi 0 Aug 19 14:01 .zhistory
Manjaro% history
    1  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    2  sed -e '/^#/d' .zshrc
    3  fc -AI
    4  ls -alF .zhistory
Manjaro% echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST $HISTFILE
10000 10000 ~/.zhistory
```

Comment: You don't have a directory called `~`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this problem. Quotes should not be used.

```
export HISTFILE=~/.zhistory
```

Comment: I had a similar problem: `zsh: locking failed for /home/pablo/.zsh/history: no such file or directory`. I couldn't find a more elegant solution than just `mkdir .zsh` (of course on `$HOME` folder.